# Como usar SHA1 no login com PHP pegando parâmetros?

Tags: php, mysql, sha1

Criei um cadastro utilizando como criptografia de senha o SHA1, onde o parâmetro de senha passo como:

```
$senha = sha1($_GET['senha']);
```

No entanto, não estou sabendo como descriptografar, ainda passando parâmetro, o `sha1()`. Tenho o exemplo a seguir, o qual já tentei colocar no parâmetro e na instrução SQL, mas não faz o login:

```
<?php
$email =$_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$query="select * from usuario_app where (email = '$email') AND (sha1(senha) = '$password'))";

$result=$con->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo json_encode($row);
    }           
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não tem que descriptografar nada, só criptografar mais!

Esse `sha1(senha)` que você colocou em seu select não irá funcionar, porque está dentro de uma string, de maneira que o php não vai reconhecer que você está chamando uma função, e que é só uma parte qualquer da string.

A maneira certa de fazer esse select é criptografando novamente a senha do usuário e comparar os 2 dados já criptografados:

```
$password = sha1($_GET['password']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario_app WHERE (email = '$email') AND (senha = '$password')";
```

Obs: `sha()` é uma função *one-way*, ou seja, é um caminho sem volta, não tem como decriptar.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes. A sua query está assim:

```
<?php
$email = 'email@empresa.com';
$password = 'senha123';
$query="select * from usuario_app where (email = '$email') AND (sha1(senha) = '$password'))";

echo $query;
```

Produzindo o sql:

```
select * from usuario_app where (email = 'email@empresa.com') AND (sha1(senha) = 'senha123'))
```

Penso que você deseja um sql similar a este:

```
select * from usuario_app where (email = 'email@empresa.com') AND (senha = sha1('senha123'))
```

onde sha1 seria a senha123 criptografada. Então, uma possivel solução seria:

```
<?php
$email = 'email@empresa.com';
$password = 'senha123';
//aplicando o hash na senha e reatribuindo na mesma variavel
$password = sha1($password);
$query="select * from usuario_app where (email = '$email') AND (senha = '$password')";

echo $query;
```

produzindo o sql:

```
select * from usuario_app where (email = 'email@empresa.com') AND (senha = '3decd49a6c6dce88c16a85b9a8e42b51aa36f1e2')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$password = sha1($_GET['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario_app WHERE email='".$email."' AND sha1='".$password."'";
```

Esse é o modelo correto.